# How to get the text out of a WKInterfaceLabel

Tags: swift, watchkit, wkinterfacelabel

It seems that labels are a bit different on the Apple Watch!

I have the following label created :

```
@IBOutlet weak var playerNameLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!
```

Then writing the label is no problem (with the "setText" method)

```
let someString = "Hello"
playerNameLabel.setText(someString)
```

But how do I get the text out of such a Label into a String-constant ???

I tried:

```
let plaerName_firstTrial: String = playerNameLabel.description  // some weird stuff
let plaerName_secondTrial: String = playerNameLabel.text // error
let plaerName_thirdTrial: String = playerNameLabel // error
let plaerName_fourthTrial: String = ?????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WKInterfacLabel` has only `setter` property and no `getter` property as defined by Apple.

Check this `WKInterfaceLabel` class declaration :

[image: Screenshot for issue]

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceLabel_class/

They only seem to allow setting the text, not getting it (programmatically).

Comment: Thank you! Therefore I need to have my own property that keeps track of the LabelText. Hmm,..., well then...

Comment: yeah kinda odd but I'm guessing as watch kit grows , a lot will change.

Comment: In severals days, you'll be able to do it :) WWDC2015

Comment: on the cusp of 2019 and you still can't do it.